# Multiple Firebase apps in one react native project

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to use several Firebase projects for Firebase Cloud Messaging in one application?
In my project I use rnfirebase and they say that

Currently, the native Firebase SDKs only provide functionality for creating secondary apps on the following services:

App Check.
Authentication.
Realtime Database.
Cloud Firestore.
Cloud Functions.
Cloud Storage.
ML.
Installations,
Remote Config.

That is, FCM is not in this list. Maybe someone knows how to substitute different google-services.json in real time.

Four firebase apps with cloud messaging, which work

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

Currently, you can only integrate one FCM project in an app. The token generated in the app will only work to that certain project.